# PyQt5 - Open widget in MDI Area after clicked menu option

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I did create in Qt Designer MainWindow Form and WidgetForm. 
In MainWindow Form i did add Mdi Area.
How i can open my Devices Widget Form in MdiArea after clicked menu option ?

> My main.py

```
from windows.devices import Ui_Form_device

 class Ui_MainWindow(object):

    def Devices(self):
        self.Form_device = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.ui = Ui_Form_device()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.Form_device)
        self.Form_device.show()

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(823, 681)

        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.centralwidget.setLayout(QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget))
        self.mdiArea = QtWidgets.QMdiArea(self.centralwidget)
        self.centralwidget.layout().addWidget(self.mdiArea)
        ...

        # menu : DEVICES
        self.actionDevices = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionDevices.setObjectName("actionDevices")
        self.actionDevices.triggered.connect(self.Devices)

        ...


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

> devices.py

```
class Ui_Form_device(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form_device):
        Form_device.setObjectName("Form_device")
        Form_device.resize(400, 300)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form_device)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 150, 111, 16))
```

Comment: `Ui_Form_device` is `Ui_Form_urzadzenia`?

Comment: Yes, i changed it

Comment: maybe this would help you refine your code https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pyqt/pyqt_multiple_document_interface.htm  in that sample your Ui_Form_device would be the QTextEdit()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try by calling `mdiArea.addSubWindow()` as follows:

```
def Devices(self):
    self.Form_device = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    self.ui = Ui_Form_device()
    self.ui.setupUi(self.Form_device)
    self.mdiArea.addSubWindow(self.Form_Device)
```

Answer (score 2):

It is recommended not to modify the class that is generated with the design made with Qt Designer, since if you make any change in the design you will overwrite a code losing the changes of the logical part. You must create a class that inherits from the widget selected in Qt Designer and fill it with the initial class.

Review the following for more recommendations:

- http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html

going to the point, what you should do is use the [`addSubWindow()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmdiarea.html#addSubWindow) method, this returns a [`QMdiSubWindow`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmdisubwindow.html), and you should show this new widget.

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    ...

class DevicesForm(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form_device):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.setupUi(self)

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.actionaction.triggered.connect(self.add_devices)

    def add_devices(self):
        w = DevicesForm(self)
        sub = self.mdiArea.addSubWindow(w)
        w.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```